# Encoding issue for " Unicode Character “ü” " while reading it from Oracle db using CX_Oracle and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, cx-oracle

I am trying to read Oracle data table output in a dataframe which I need to compare against another dataframe.

Oracle has str value Unicode Character “ü” which is appearing as 'u' in dataframe.

Code I tried:

```py
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle

conn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(host='hostname', port='1521', service_name= 'SomeName')
sqlconn = cx_Oracle.connect( user='Username', password='$$$$$', dsn=conn)
sqlquery = "Select statement"
df2 = pd.read_sql(sqlquery, sqlconn)

print(df2)
**UBERX**,2003-10-01 00:00:00,I,N/A,Not Available

Expected 
**ÜBERX**,2003-10-01 00:00:00,I,N/A,Not Available
```

If i export the output to csv

```py
df2.to_csv('/home/user/05June_1_ORA.csv', index=False)
```

In Unix loc:

```sh
bash-4.2$ file -i *
05June_1_ORA.csv: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

This data is getting ingested to oracle using a csv and its encoding is utf-8

```sh
sourcefile_05June_1.csv:     text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

Please let me know how can I resolve it.

Comment: What version of python & pandas are you using? And you're positive that the ü character is in the SQL database?

Comment: Python 3.6.5
Pandas  '0.23.0'
Yes Oracle db has same value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you connect to the database, ensure that you set the encoding. This will become default in cx_Oracle 8, but for now, do this:

```
sqlconn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='Username', password='$$$$$', dsn=conn,
        encoding="UTF-8", nencoding="UTF-8")
```

Comment: Great! Glad it was helpful!

Comment: AnthonyTuininga is the producer of cx_oracle @Rohit as far as I know ...

Comment: Yes, I am . :-)